# Ansible: Remove item from dict

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I have a situation where i am trying to remove the item from a list. but i am not getting expected result. Please help me what I am doing wrong here?

here is the list :

```
    "get_ec2_id.instances[0].tags": {
    "Name": "test-db-system-2",
    "aws:cloudformation:logical-id": "DBInstance",
    "aws:cloudformation:stack-id": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789012:stack/test-db-system-2/0115v0a0-5d44-17e8-a024-503ama4a5qd1",
    "aws:cloudformation:stack-name": "test-db-system-2",
    "dbsystem:stack": "test-db-system-2",
    "dbsystem:type": "db"
}
```

}

I am trying to remove the all "aws:cloudformation" tags from a list using below filter:

```
    "{{ get_ec2_id.instances[0].tags | reject('search','aws:') | list }}"
```

I am getting the below result:

```
    ok: [10.52.8.101] => {
"instances_tags": [
    "dbsystem:type",
    "dbsystem:stack",
    "Name"
]
    }
```

but I am expected below result :

```
      "instances_tags": [
    "dbsystem:stack": "test-db-system-2",
    "dbsystem:type": "db"
    "Name" : "test-db-system-2",
]
  }
```

Help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Is that the actual name of the system you're working with?

Also, you're starting with a dict and forcing it to a list. I'm not sure what kind of unintended consequences that may have.

Comment: what happens if you remove `| list` from your filter?

Comment: That's **not** a list!　And your expectation is an incorrect JSON too.

Comment: @smiller171 if I remove a list from a filter, i am getting below output. "ok: [10.52.8.101] => {
    "instances_tags": "<generator object _select_or_reject at 0x7f741ec4f460>"
}"

Comment: @techraf , output is  a array ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generic solution where input is a dict and blacklist is a list:

```
---
- set_fact:
    blacklist:
      - bad1
      - bad2
- set_fact:
    output: {}
- name: remove blacklisted items from input
  set_fact:
    output: "{{ output | combine({item.key: item.value}) }}"
  when: item.key not in blacklist
  loop: "{{ input | dict2items }}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Given the data

```yaml
  get_ec2_id:
    instances:
    - tags:
        Name: test-db-system-2
        aws:cloudformation:logical-id: DBInstance
        aws:cloudformation:stack-id: arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789012:stack/test-db-system-2/0115v0a0-5d44-17e8-a024-503ama4a5qd1
        aws:cloudformation:stack-name: test-db-system-2
        dbsystem:stack: test-db-system-2
        dbsystem:type: db
```

---

Use [rejectattr](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#rejectattr). For example

```yaml
  dict2: "{{ get_ec2_id.instances.0.tags|
             dict2items|
             rejectattr('key', 'search', 'aws:')|
             items2dict }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  dict2:
    Name: test-db-system-2
    dbsystem:stack: test-db-system-2
    dbsystem:type: db
```

---

Then, convert the dictionary into a list of dictionaries

```yaml
  instances_tags: "{{ dict2|
                      dict2items|
                      json_query('[].[[key, value]]')|
                      map('community.general.dict')|
                      list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  instances_tags:
  - Name: test-db-system-2
  - dbsystem:stack: test-db-system-2
  - dbsystem:type: db
```

Comment: Thank you for this. What other options besides 'key' and 'search' do the `rejectattr` provides? the documents doesn't show anything

Comment: The [document](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#rejectattr) describes the parameters very clearly: *"Filters a sequence of objects by applying a **test** to the specified **attribute** of each object, and rejecting the objects with the test succeeding"*. The first parameter is any attribute of the dictionary and the second parameter is any test e.g. [tests](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#tests). *"If no test is specified, the attribute’s value will be evaluated as a boolean"*. Test it.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
---
- name: dictionary
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  connection: local



  vars:
    get_ec2_id:
      instances:
        tags:
          Name: "test-db-system-2"
          "aws:cloudformation:logical-id": "DBInstance"
          "aws:cloudformation:stack-id": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789012:stack/test-db-system-2/0115v0a0-5d44-17e8-a024-503ama4a5qd1"
          "aws:cloudformation:stack-name": "test-db-system-2"
          "dbsystem:stack": "test-db-system-2"
          "dbsystem:type": "db"
    dict2: {}

  tasks:

    - name: Fact1
      set_fact:
        dict: "{{ get_ec2_id.instances.tags }}"

    - name: Debug1
      debug:
        var: dict

    - name: Fact2
      set_fact:
        dict2: "{{ dict2 | combine({item.key: item.value}) }}"
      when: "{{ item.key.find('aws:') }}"
      with_dict: "{{ dict }}"

    - name: Debug2
      debug:
        var: dict2
```

**Output:**

```
TASK [Debug2] ******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "dict2": {
        "Name": "test-db-system-2", 
        "dbsystem:stack": "test-db-system-2", 
        "dbsystem:type": "db"
    }
}
```

Comment: A little bit of explanation or some links would have been better. Otherwise it is like a pill to swallow.

Answer (score 0):

from ansible 2.5, you can use `ansible.utils.remove_keys`, e.g.

```
  - name: Remove element from dictionary
    set_fact:
      dict: "{{ dict | ansible.utils.remove_keys('key_name')  }}"
```

Source:

- https://ftith.github.io/posts/ansible-data-structures/#remove-element-from-dictionary
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/remove_keys_filter.html